# What model should I use? Time series count data grouped into provinces. R

Tags: r, time-series, multilevel-analysis, count-data

I have daily observations on the count of a variable, with 1,000 daily observations across 15 different provinces, for a total of 15,000 observations. On certain days, there is an exposure, which may decrease or increase the count. I am interested in estimating the effect of the exposure. What is an appropriate model?

I have so far tried a multilevel generalized model (lme4), with a poisson distribution and random effects for provinces (to capture spatial autocorrelation) and weeks (to capture temporal autocorrelation), together with the exposure variable and a few control variables. Is this a viable approach? What alternatives do I have?

Further information: The exposure variable is generally 0 but is 1 for some provinces on some days (usually for 3-30 consecutive days). I have very no control variables currently, because there is no data available. My reasoning was that the random effects for provinces and weeks would capture a fair amount of the unobserved variation.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your exposure variable? Does it change from day to day within each province? What about the control variables - are they collected daily? Are you interested in modelling things on the daily scale or a coarser scale (e.g., week or month)?

Comment: Thanks, Isabella. The exposure variable is generally 0 but is 1 for some provinces on some days (usually for 3-30 consecutive days). I have very no control variables currently, because there is no data available. My reasoning was that the random effects for provinces and weeks would capture a fair amount of the unobserved variation.

Comment: Can you please add that new information as an edit to the original question?

Comment: If you look at plots of your count dependent variable as a function of day for each province, what do you see? If you see strong temporal patterns, then a better way to capture those patterns would be to (i) include only random province effects in your model and (ii) include a smooth term of day in the fixed effects portion of your model. This would allow you to control for the temporal patterns present in your response variable and would suggest a generalized additive mixed effects model (GAMM) for your data, which you could fit in R with the gamm() function from the mgcv package.

Comment: If you could post one or two plots as the one suggested in my previous comment, then we would understand better what you are dealing with. The other thing you should look at is the distribution of your count variable for each province - maybe using an R command like plot(table(count_variable)), so that you can see if you have excessive zeroes present in that distribution.